# Cython on windows: DLL load failed

Tags: python, windows, cython

I'm installing a cython module and then attempt to run a file that loads it as follows

```
(myenv3) C:lcp>python setup.py build_ext --inplace
running build_ext
copying build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pathlcp_simplelcp.cp38-win_amd64.pyd ->
copying build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pathlcp_mcp.cp38-win_amd64.pyd ->

(myenv3) C:lcp>python obstacle.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "obstacle.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pathlcp_mcp import interact_standalonec
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing pathlcp_mcp: The specified module could not be found.
```

I'm doing this both from the same anaconda environment (`myenv3`), and the same python interpreter. I then go to the folder, and see two files:

- pathlcp_mcp.cp38-win_amd64.pyd
- pathlcp_simplelcp.cp38-win_amd64.pyd

This cython module worked flawlessly on my linux machine... without uploading the entire module, what could be the source?

Comment: Did you build the module using the same interpreter you're attempting to use for running it?

Comment: @AKX yes, the same python interpreter. I cleaned up the question to get this point across.

Comment: Then it sounds like the DLL depends on another DLL that's not on the interpreter path. You could try https://www.dependencywalker.com/ to find out what's missing.